# Error in installing zipline in Python 3.4

Tags: python, zipline

I need your help to install zipline.

I am beginner in Python coding but I faced with huge barrier now...
I tried to zipline in my python and I followed below process.

1. my python version is 3.6 but zipline supports 2.7 and 3.4. So I installed 3.4 python like below:
   conda create -n previous python =3.4.1 anaconda

In addition, I installed visual C++ 2010.

2. activate previous
3. pip install zipline

But my computer still shows below error message. I am not sure how to install zipline and solve this error. My computer is window 7, intelcore i7-4712 64bit and I installed anaconda 4.0.0(32bit)

---

(C:\Anaconda3) C:\Users\sktsuser>activate previous

(previous) C:\Users\sktsuser>python --version
Python 3.4.1 :: Anaconda 2.1.0 (32-bit)

(previous) C:\Users\sktsuser>pip install zipline

File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\previous\lib\site-packages\setuptools-5.8-py3.4.egg\se
tuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1043, in run_setup

distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Setup script exited with error: command 'C:\An
aconda3\mingw\bin\gcc.exe' failed with exit status 1

---

Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\sktsuser\A
ppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_sktsuser\zipline
Storing debug log for failure in C:\Users\sktsuser\pip\pip.log

(previous) C:\Users\sktsuser>

Comment: Maybe check these steps, someone had same problem and suggested this fix: https://github.com/quantopian/zipline/issues/650#issuecomment-167050802

Answer (score 0):

Try using conda installation with quantopian source instead of pip as below:

```
conda install -c Quantopian zipline
```

Answer (score 0):

That is one of the main reasons they recommend you to use virtualenv.

Here they have some details how to install using virtualenv

http://www.zipline.io/development-guidelines.html

```
$ mkvirtualenv zipline
$ ./etc/ordered_pip.sh ./etc/requirements.txt
$ pip install -r ./etc/requirements_dev.txt
$ pip install -r ./etc/requirements_blaze.txt
```

Note for this you need to checkout their source code or the requirements.txt from github: https://github.com/quantopian/zipline/tree/master/etc

That way you can create a virtual env with the right python needed by zipline